# FFMPEG throws error while converting WEBM/MP4 audio files from MediaRecorder to MP3

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, mp4, webm, web-mediarecorder

I use [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) to record the audio from the browser and then upload it to my server (ARM-based Linux machine - AWS Lambda Function, if it matters). Based on the browser type, I get either an MP4 file (for the Safari browser) OR a WEBM file (for every other browser) from the MediaRecorder. The audio is converted to Base64 string and posted to my server with FFMPEG.

**MediaRecorder implementation**

```
const audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);
const MediaRecorder = window['MediaRecorder'];
const mimeType = MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/webm') ? 'audio/webm' : 'audio/mp4';
const recordingFileExtension = MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/webm') ? 'webm' : 'mp4';
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(audioStream, { mimeType });
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = convertBlobAndUploadChunk;
mediaRecorder.start(30 * 1000); // timeslice needs to be in ms
// When user stops recording
mediaRecorder.stop();
audioStream.getTracks().forEach( t => { t.stop(); });
// To convert the audio blob to string
function convertBlobToBase64(blob) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        reader.onload = () => {
            const tmpStr = reader.result.toString();
            resolve(tmpStr.substring(tmpStr.indexOf('base64,') + 7));
        };
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });
}

let blobCount = 0;
async function convertBlobAndUploadChunk(blobEvent) {
    if (!blobEvent.data || blobEvent.data.size === 0) return;

    blobCount++;

    const recordData = JSON.stringify({
        M: {
            blobCount,
            //some other meta data
        },
        D: await convertBlobToBase64(audioBlob),
    });

    await angularHttpClient.post(apiUrl, recordData, new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-api-key': apiKey,
    })).toPromise();
}
```

On my server, I convert the WEBM/MP4 file to an MP3 file for better cross-browser compatibility and to enable scrubbing.

**Backend Lambda Implementation**

```
const FFMpegCommand = require('fluent-ffmpeg'); // v2.1.2
new FFMpegCommand()
        .input(originalFile)
        .on('end', (error, stdOut, stdError) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        })
        .save(convertedFile);
```

This works perfectly fine 99.9% of the time but FFMPEG throws one of the following errors for 0.1% of the time:

**Error 1: Invalid data found when processing input**

*error reading header*

```
ffmpeg version 4.4-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the 
FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
libavutil 56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
libavcodec 58.134.100 / 58.134.100
libavformat 58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
libavdevice 58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
libavfilter 7.110.100 / 7.110.100
libswscale 5. 9.100 / 5. 9.100
libswresample 3. 9.100 / 3. 9.100
libpostproc 55. 9.100 / 55. 9.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7232f40] could not find corresponding trex (id 1)
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7232f40] could not find corresponding track id 0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7232f40] trun track id unknown, no tfhd was found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7232f40] error reading header
/tmp/long-filename-of-140chars-to-keep-files-unique.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

*EBML Header parsing failed*

```
ffmpeg version 4.4-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
libavutil 56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
libavcodec 58.134.100 / 58.134.100
libavformat 58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
libavdevice 58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
libavfilter 7.110.100 / 7.110.100
libswscale 5. 9.100 / 5. 9.100
libswresample 3. 9.100 / 3. 9.100
libpostproc 55. 9.100 / 55. 9.100
[matroska,webm @ 0x7595f40] Format matroska,webm detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[matroska,webm @ 0x7595f40] EBML header parsing failed
/tmp/long-filename-of-140chars-to-keep-files-unique.webm: Invalid data found when processing input
```

*No specific details*

```
ffmpeg version 4.4-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
libavutil 56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
libavcodec 58.134.100 / 58.134.100
libavformat 58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
libavdevice 58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
libavfilter 7.110.100 / 7.110.100
libswscale 5. 9.100 / 5. 9.100
libswresample 3. 9.100 / 3. 9.100
libpostproc 55. 9.100 / 55. 9.100
/tmp/long-filename-of-140chars-to-keep-files-unique.webm: Invalid data found when processing input
```

**Error 2: Output file #0 does not contain any stream**

```
ffmpeg version 4.4-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
libavutil 56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
libavcodec 58.134.100 / 58.134.100
libavformat 58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
libavdevice 58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
libavfilter 7.110.100 / 7.110.100
libswscale 5. 9.100 / 5. 9.100
libswresample 3. 9.100 / 3. 9.100
libpostproc 55. 9.100 / 55. 9.100
[mpegts @ 0x5d19f40] Format mpegts detected only with low score of 2, misdetection possible!
[mpegts @ 0x5d19f40] Could not detect TS packet size, defaulting to non-FEC/DVHS
Input #0, mpegts, from '/tmp/long-filename-of-140chars-to-keep-files-unique.webm':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Output #0, mp3, to '/tmp/long-filename-of-140chars-to-keep-files-unique.mp3':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Thanks for reading, any help/suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: It's 99.9% not FFmpeg's problem (both errors). Somewhere in your chain, your data is being corrupted.

Comment: "The audio is converted to Base64 string and posted to my server with FFMPEG."  Most likely unrelated to your problem, but don't do this.  There's no reason for it.  You're adding a ton of extra memory usage and 33% bandwidth for no benefit.  Post binary data instead.

Comment: "On my server, I convert the WEBM/MP4 file to an MP3 file for better cross-browser compatibility and to enable scrubbing."  WebM and MP4 files are very compatible.  You could always just re-mux the audio track into the same file format to fix the issue with scrubbing, and then you won't lose additional audio quality.

Comment: Without any code here, it's impossible to help you further.  As @kesh says, the problem is somewhere else.  Your data is getting mangled.  You're probably missing the header segment or getting them out of order or something.  But, there's no code so we can't really help you.

Comment: @Brad I have added my code, can you please have a look now?

Comment: Still missing `convertBlobAndUploadChunk`.

Comment: @Brad, that function doesn't modify the audio chunk (other than converting it into base64). It wraps the base64 string in a JSON object with some meta data for the audio. If you still think that you need it, I will add it.

Comment: It's probably the most important part...

Comment: @Brad, added the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky to debug this without more code but I think Brad is on to something, sounds like the data isn't complete or mangled.

If it is corrupted data being ingested then you might want to consider putting something before the conversion to ensure that it is valid.

As a proof of concept I created this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg

COPY valid.sh /valid.sh
RUN chmod 755 valid.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/valid.sh" ]
```

and created a file called `valid.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export INPUT_FILE
export OUTPUT_FILE

echo Looking for ${INPUT_FILE} exporting to $OUTPUT_FILE

/usr/bin/ffmpeg -v error -i /input/${INPUT_FILE} -f null - 2>errors.log

if [[ $(cat errors.log) ]]; then
    echo "Errors found! Source video isn't valid."
    exit 1
fi

/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /input/${INPUT_FILE} -vn -ab 128k -ar 44100 -y /output/${OUTPUT_FILE};
```

To run it:

```
docker build -t test ./
docker run -it --env INPUT_FILE=broken.webm --env OUTPUT_FILE=test123.mp3 --rm --name test -v C:/Users/me/Desktop/example:/input -v C:/Users/me/Desktop/output:/output test:latest
```

If the webm file is invalid it returns:

```
Looking for broken.webm exporting to test123.mp3
Errors found! Source video isn't valid.`
```

... otherwise:

```
Looking for working.webm exporting to test123.mp3
ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/input/working.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : http://sourceforge.net/projects/yamka
    creation_time   : 2010-05-20T12:00:13.000000Z
  Duration: 00:01:57.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 582 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 540x360, SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (vorbis (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp3, to '/output/test123.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libmp3lame
size=    1840kB time=00:01:57.71 bitrate= 128.1kbits/s speed= 209x    
video:0kB audio:1840kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.024520%
```